# Change the width of column in the Excel sheet via export in kendo

Tags: ember.js, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo grid in my ember app. I have introduced export to Excel in kendo. But after downloading the Excel sheet, I want to resize the width of the column within the Excel sheet .. how to deal with it?

Here is my code:

```
myGrid.bind("excelExport", function (e) {
    // console.log(">>"+);
    var str = e.sender.columns;
    var title = str.map(function(d) { return d['title']; }).indexOf('Action');
    var documentKey = str.map(function(d) { return d['field']; }).indexOf('documentKey'); 

    if (!exportFlag) {  
        e.sender.hideColumn(documentKey);
        e.sender.hideColumn(title);
        e.preventDefault();

        exportFlag = true;

        setTimeout(function () {
            e.sender.saveAsExcel();
        });
    } else {
        e.sender.showColumn(documentKey);
        e.sender.showColumn(title);
        exportFlag = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the format of cells during export to excel, you can setup a [`kendo.ooxml.Workbook`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ooxml/workbook.html#kendoooxmlworkbook).

This way you can modify the format of each cell, row, column etc by building up an array containing `columns`, `rows` and `cells`:

```
var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
  sheets: [
      {
          columns: [ { width: 100 }, { width: 200 } ],
          rows: [
            {
              cells: [
                { value: "this column is 100px" }, { value: "this column is 200px" }
              ]
            }
          ]
      }
  ]
});
```

In your case you will need to build up the data you wish to send to the workbook based on what is in the grid datasource.

I have attached a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ipAke/3) to demonstrate an example of all the above in action.